# Slutsky's theorem

Tags: convergence

If I have a set of $N$ i.i.d. random variables $X$ with sample mean $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N X_i$, does Slutsky's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem imply that
$$
    E\left[\frac{X_i X_i}{\bar{X}}\right] = \frac{E[X_i^2]}{E[\bar{X}]}.
$$
I'm not particularly familiar with the notation used in probability theory so the wiki is not clear to me.  If the above is not true, are there certain certain constraints I can place on $X$ which make it true?

Comment: Slutsky's theorem is about convergence, and in what you wrote there is no convergence involved, so Slutsky has nothing to say about your formula.  Apart from that, generally, your formula is invalid, wrong.

Comment: What would your formula say for random variables of zero expectation?

Comment: I see what you mean, it would appear to be undefined for variables of zero expectation.  Can anyone explain Slutsky's theorem as I do not understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is evident in the link you provided, Slutsky's lemma is concerned with probability limits and convergence in distribution, not with expected values. Moreover, the equality stated in the question is not correct, because (apart from the other issues raised in the comments), the numerator is not independent from the denominator, and so the expected value does not distribute. And, by construction, you cannot make it independent by "placing restrictions on $X$".
But the equality does hold "asymptotically".

Assume that $E(X_i^2)$ exists and is finite. Then $E(X_i)$ also exists and is finite. Make the additional assumpion that $E(X_i) =\mu \neq 0$.

Let's apply Slutsky's lemma: $X_i^2$ trivially converges in distribution to itself (it does not depend on $N$), while $\bar X$ converges in probability to the non-zero mean $\mu$, which is a constant. Then Slutsky's lemma says that

$$\frac{X_i ^2}{\bar{X}} \xrightarrow{d} \frac{X_i^2 }{E(\bar X)} \equiv Z$$

The expected value of the limiting random variable will be

$$E(Z) = E\left(\frac{X_i^2 }{E(\bar X)}\right) = \frac{E[X_i^2]}{E[\bar{X}]}$$

where here we "distributed" the expected value because the denominator is a constant.

***But***, the moments of the limiting distribution are not necessarily equal to the limit of the moments of the finite sample distribution. We need an additional condition for that, which is (for our particular case)

$$\exists \;\delta>0:\; E\left(\left|\frac{X_i ^2}{\bar{X}}\right|^{1+\delta}\right) < M<\infty \;\;\forall N$$

Then, what we can say is that

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}E\left[\frac{X_i^2 }{\bar{X}}\right] = E(Z)  = \frac{E[X_i^2]}{E[\bar{X}]}$$

Another way to approach the matter, more intuitively but less formally, is to think that as $N$ grows very large, $X_i$ and $\bar X$ tend to become independent, since a single  $X_i$ contributes relatively less and less to $\bar X$. So at the limit, we can distribute the expected value.

Comment: The second and less formal "proof" you have described in your final paragraph is what lead me to believe the truth of statement.  I'm very glad it can be expressed more formally.  Forgive my ignorance but in your last equation you have a limit of N tending to infinity and also an expectation.  Doesn't the expectation imply N tending to infinity?  Also, I'm clearly not an expert on these matters but would like to know of any literature that can get me up to speed.  Can you recommend books?

Comment: @mrkprc1 No, the expectation does _not_ imply N tending to infinity, and evidently this is what confused you in the first place. So the statement is true _only at the limit_. As for books, there are various threads here on CV that provide lists of books. I would suggest to browse them, and it they don't suit you, to post a new question describing your current knowledge situation and the area you want to focus, asking for targeted literature.

Comment: Hit this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references   to browse all questions with the tag "references".